# Where to put Channel, ClientId in the Google Maps SDK register for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have written Swift code. I wanted to use `durationInTraffic` in a register with Google Maps SDK for iOS.

Here it says Maps for work customers should include their clientId and channel to register. But where exactly do I put the clientId and channel to register? Below is my code:

```swift
import UIKit

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let googleMapsApiKey = "MY_GOOGLE_IOS_API_KEY"

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey(googleMapsApiKey)
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Equivalent in Javascript is: <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&channel=YOUR_CHANNEL"></script>

Comment: where are you making the request?

Comment: Are you talking about this? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/

Comment: Sorry, it is when registering the SDK. I already edited the question.

Comment: Can you share the link you are following?

Comment: After searching the forums, it turned out that you can not assign a channel to register Google Maps SDK for iOS:
https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/reports/usage-reports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching the forums, it turned out that you can not assign a channel to register Google Maps SDK for iOS:
 developers.google.com/maps/premium/reports/usage-reports